# c++ try and catch not ending program

Tags: c++

I know this is a lot of code but it's just a program that prompts for speed, altitude, fuel, and direction and catches any errors. If an error is thrown then the program should stop and if there is no error than the program should just display all the values. My problem is that whenever the last try-catch statement(InvalidDirection) catches an error the program still runs the showAll function.

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class FlightInfo
{
private:
   int absoluteAltitude = 0;
   int speed = 0;
   int fuelLevel = 0;
   int direction = 0;
public:
   class InvalidSpeed
   {};
   class InvalidDirection
   {};
   class InvalidFuelLevel
   {};
   class InvalidAltitude
   {};
       
   // setters

   //valid 0-10000
   void setAbsoluteAltitude(int alt) {
       if (alt >= 0 && alt <= 10000) {
           absoluteAltitude = alt;
       }
       else {
           throw InvalidAltitude();
       }
   }
   
   //valid 0 - 650
   void setSpeed(int currentSpeed) {
       if (currentSpeed >= 0 && currentSpeed <= 650) {
           speed = currentSpeed;
       }
       else {
           throw InvalidSpeed();
       }
   }
   
   // Valid 0 - 100
   void setFuelLevel(int level) {
       if (level >= 0 && level <= 100) {
           fuelLevel = level;
       }
       else {
           throw InvalidFuelLevel();
       }
   }
   
   // valid 0-359
   void setDirection(int heading) {
       if (heading >= 0 && heading <= 359) {
           direction = heading;
       }
       else {
           throw InvalidDirection();
       }
   }

   // getters
   int getAbsoluteAltitude() {
       return absoluteAltitude;
   }
   int getSpeed() {
       return speed;
   }
   int getFuelLevel() {
       return fuelLevel;
   }
   int getDirection() {
       return direction;
   }


   void showAll() {
       cout <<"Altitude     = " << getAbsoluteAltitude() << endl;
       cout <<"Speed        = " << getSpeed() << endl;
       cout <<"FuelLevel    = " << getFuelLevel() << endl;
       cout <<"Direction    = " << getDirection() << endl;
   }
};
```

Here is my driver/cpp file

```
#include "FlightInfo.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    FlightInfo flight;
    
    int getTheSpeed;
    int getTheAltitude;
    int getTheFuel;
    int getTheDirection;
    
    
    cout << "Enter Speed ";
    cin >> getTheSpeed;
    try {
        flight.setSpeed(getTheSpeed);
    }
    catch (FlightInfo::InvalidSpeed)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: speed less than 0 or greater than 650" << endl;
    }
    
    
    cout << "Enter altitude ";
    cin >> getTheAltitude;
    try {
        flight.setAbsoluteAltitude(getTheAltitude);
    }
    catch (FlightInfo::InvalidAltitude)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Altitude less than 0 or greater than 10000" << endl;
    }
    
    
    cout << "Enter Fuel Level ";
    cin >> getTheFuel;
    try {
        flight.setFuelLevel(getTheFuel);
    }
    catch (FlightInfo::InvalidFuelLevel)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Fuel level less than 0 or greater than 100" << endl;
    }
    
    
    cout << "Enter direction ";
    cin >> getTheDirection;
    try {
        flight.setDirection(getTheDirection);
    }
    catch (FlightInfo::InvalidDirection)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Direction is less than 0 or greater than 359" << endl;
    }
    
    flight.showAll();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unlike languages like Java, C# or Python, a thrown exception in C++ could be quite expensive. Therefore it's not recommended to use them for "simple" input validation. Only use them for truly exceptional events, things that are hard to recover from.

Comment: Maybe you should return after the printing, or rethrow?

Comment: As for your problem, none of the `catch` clauses exits the program. The program will happily continue after the `catch` clauses. If you don't want the program to continue, then you must explicitly tell it not to.

Comment: Another note on input validation: You don't have enough of it. If the user inputs a word instead of a number for `getTheSpeed` then `getTheSpeed` will be zero which you accept. The problem is that you don't catch the problem, and that the word will still be in the input buffer to be read by the *next* input statement, which you then again will miss. Furthermore, if you want to only allow non-negative numbers, use `unsigned` instead, and the input operation will not accept negative numbers.

Comment: @Some programmer dude - use of exceptions ought to depend upon context. A single user program that uses exceptions for input validation is not likely to see any performance impact whatsoever. OTOH validation on a server handling thousands of requests or more per second would probably want to avoid using exceptions. In general, don't throw away easy to understand code in favour of performance until you know performance is an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Problem:

Even when the last try-catch statements catch an error the program still runs the showAll function.

### The Reason:

None of the catch clauses exits the program.

### Possible Solutions:

1. In every `catch` clause, put a `return <any number other than zero>`.
2. Do not `catch` the Exceptions.
3. In every `catch` clause, put an `exit` clause.

Comment: @Seth Updated answer, please check.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I see the issue with what you described. Are you expecting when invalid direction is thrown the program does not get to `showall()`?:

```
cout << "Enter direction ";
cin >> getTheDirection;
try {
    flight.setDirection(getTheDirection);
}
catch (FlightInfo::InvalidDirection)
{
    cout << "ERROR: Direction is less than 0 or greater than 359" << endl;
}

flight.showAll();
```

But here you are "catch"ing the exception and handling it. Therefore the program continues. If you want it to end you will need to re-throw or not catch the exception:

```
cout << "Enter direction ";
cin >> getTheDirection;
//try {
    flight.setDirection(getTheDirection);
//}
//catch (FlightInfo::InvalidDirection)
//{
//    cout << "ERROR: Direction is less than 0 or greater than 359" << endl;
//}

flight.showAll();
```

Now your inner "throw" will not be caught and your program will end.